# Word spacing in CoreText

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, core-text

Is there a way to set a custom word spacing in CoreText?
I have looked around the paragraph properties where I would have expected to see this but found nothing.

Comment: Did you check the [Core Text String Attributes Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Carbon/Reference/CoreText_StringAttributes_Ref/Reference/reference.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have deep experience in this but AFAIK you cannot adjust the space between words. So my list of possible solutions would be:

- Adjust the kern value, however this will also adjust the space between letter which may not be what you want.
- Add extra spaces. Crude, but you can increase the space between words by replace a single space with two.
- (Really advanced) start adjusting individual glyphs. The best example I have found for doing is here: http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/core-text about 2/3rds down the author shows how to access the individual glyphs and adjust their settings.